# Sending AJAX data to controller (Yii-Framework)

Tags: jquery, yii

I'm trying to implement an up/downvote system for our web application. Currently the user can 'post' a question on our site. When the user goes to the browse section of our site, they are shown a list of all the questions currently posed on the website.

When the user clicks the up or downvote link, the database should be updated via AJAX (i.e. I don't want to redirect the user, or have the page refresh).

How do I retrieve the question associated with each up/downvote link, and then send that data to the controller?

`site/browse:`

```
<?php
    /*
     * @var $model Question
     */

    //loop through all the given questions
    foreach($model as $q)
    {        
        //add the upvote and downvote (text for now)
        echo CHtml::ajaxLink('up', array('question/upvote'));
        echo ("&nbsp - &nbsp;");
        echo CHtml::ajaxLink('down', array('question/downvote'));
        echo '<br />';

        echo CHtml::link($q['name'], array('question/browse/'.$q['_id']));
        echo "<br />Description: " . $q["description"] . "<br />";
        echo "Owner: " . $q["user_id"] . "<br />";

        $timeStamp = new Timestamp($q['timestamp']);

        echo $timeStamp->getDifferenceString() . "<br /><br />";
     }
?>
```

`question controller:`

```
...
 public function upvote()
        {
            //should retrieve question_id and then update database accordingly
            //e.g. UPDATE Question SET value = value + 1 WHERE Question.id = id
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the id of the question getting the upvote in the URL of the ajax request, or as POST data in the ajax request. I would recommend using POST data through the jQuery AJAX call, but here I'll show how to do it with the code you have supplied.

```
<?php
    /*
     * @var $model Question
     */

    //loop through all the given questions
    foreach($model as $q)
    {        
        //add the upvote and downvote (text for now)
        echo CHtml::ajaxLink('up', array('question/upvote',array('id'=>$q['_id'])));
        echo ("&nbsp - &nbsp;");
        echo CHtml::ajaxLink('down', array('question/downvote',array('id'=>$q['_id'])));
        echo '<br />';

        echo CHtml::link($q['name'], array('question/browse/'.$q['_id']));
        echo "<br />Description: " . $q["description"] . "<br />";
        echo "Owner: " . $q["user_id"] . "<br />";

        $timeStamp = new Timestamp($q['timestamp']);

        echo $timeStamp->getDifferenceString() . "<br /><br />";
     }
?>
```

Once you have the ID, then in your question controller you would modify the upvote() method as shown.

question controller:

```
...
 public function upvote($id)
        {
            //you have the question id, now you can update database accordingly
            //e.g. UPDATE Question SET value = value + 1 WHERE Question.id = id
        }
...
```

This will get you started. You should look at using jQuery to generate the upvote/downvote requests and handle the responses - and I don't mean the jQuery automatically generated by the ajaxLink() method. You can also look at making the url look nicer with a route to handle upvote and downvote requests.